# Where is the Segmentation Fault in this code?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Hello I'm an amateur programmer, and to make it worse it has been a while since I've done any programming so I decided to refresh my memory with some easy Topcoder problems. The first one I did ended up being a segment fault, and right now that's beyond what I can figure out for myself, can anyone help me understand where the segment fault came from. Here is the code.

```
vector<int> Bonuses (vector<int> points)
{
    int totalPoints = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i != points.size(); ++i)
    {
        totalPoints += points[i];
    }

    vector<int> percentage;
    int percentageLeft = 100;
    int truncatedPercentage;

    for (int i = 0; i != points.size(); ++i)
    {
        truncatedPercentage = points[i]/totalPoints;
        percentage.push_back(truncatedPercentage);
        percentageLeft -= truncatedPercentage;
    }
    for (int i = 1;i <= percentageLeft; ++i)
    {
        percentage[percentage.size() - i] += 1;
    }
    return percentage;


}
```

Comment: You'are violating memory access may going beyond the limits of an array.

Comment: You should really learn to use the debugger [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/). When getting a crash, like this segmentation fault, a debugger will help you pinpoint the location of the crash, and also let you examine variables to help you understand the cause of the crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a logic error in your program.  Change this:

```
truncatedPercentage = points[i]/totalPoints;
```

to this:

```
truncatedPercentage = points[i] * 100 / totalPoints;
```

Otherwise the percentage will be almost always 0, and the `percentageLeft` will be 100.  That is why `percentage[percentage.size() - i] += 1` is segfaulting as AndersK already found before me.  The index is typically negative.

That said, I am uncertain on whether mixing pushbacks and direct assignments gives you the most readable code that you could have here.

Answer (score 3):

Probably here

```
for (int i = 1;i <= percentageLeft; ++i)
{
    percentage[percentage.size() - i] += 1;
}
```

If `percentageLeft` is larger than the size of vector. If `i` exceeds the size of the vector, than you're reading before its memory location which results in an access violation (segfault).

Answer (score 1):

```
percentage[percentage.size() - i] += 1;
```

`std::map` would have served your purposes better than `std::vector` for the 'percentage'.